# symfony configuration parameter storage entity

Tags: symfony, parameters, configuration, storage

In a symfony project, I'm looking the best way to storage some configuration parameter such as the application is online, offline or accesible.
I need to change this value constantly from the web interface with my role ADMIN, so I could put the application offline during maintenance period, but for the ADMIN role the application will be available (not for other users). In each redirect, I ask for this configuration (this is already agreed).

I thougth create an entity with this configuration param, but this table will have no more than one row, so I'm asking me if this is the best way. Is there any other way to storage this param in Symfony?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Having a "settings" table for this sort of things is a common solution. You can manage them easily with [SettingsBundle](https://github.com/dmishh/SettingsBundle).

Alternatively you could use Symfony Cache to store it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43785356/1637446